# What is the data type of SHA-a output?

Tags: types, hex, sha1, sha

**SHA-1** produces **a 160-bit** *(20-byte*) hash value known as a message digest – typically rendered as *a hexadecimal number*, *40 digits long*, so is this (*20-byte*) of hex value as an array or just normal hex value?

This is my code: so what is the datatype of the output:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
public class MessageDigestExample {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

String input = "This is a message";
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
System.out.println("input : " + input);
hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input));
System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(hash.digest()));
```

} }

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. It is 20 bytes of data, nothing more

Comment: yes, but is it as an array?

Comment: If you put it in an array then it is in an array. It’s just data, how you handle it is your choice. It’s the same as asking if a file on disk is an array

Comment: yes, this is what I need to know, because I need this output to be input as IV in AES algorithm as an array like:
 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
so do I need to convert from HEX to ByteArray?

Comment: That is another question. Maybe you should edit your question to include all the relevant code, explanation on what you’re doing, tag the environment, language, etc. We don’t know what you’re doing so you’ll have to give all the information.

Comment: @ Sami Kuhmonen I put the code

Comment: That’s not the code you were talking about. And you clearly know the datatypes in this code. And the output is just text since you’re printing it out. There’s nothing about IV or anything. And please do fix the tags also to show the platform and language so people will find the question, but first please explain properly what you want to do *after* this code since that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question but here are some answers:

When you use a SHA-1 hash function, it converts some value you gave it in input, into another value. Whereas your input value can be as long as you want, the digest result will be fixed (your 160-bits result).

As I understand your question, you want to give some "type" to what you set in input and what you get in output. I think that's the point you misunderstand: whatever data you set in input, they are juste bits (or bytes if you prefer to group them). What you get in output are also bits (or bytes). Then, it is your choice to represent them as you prefer: as an hexadecimal value, or as several hexadecimal values put into an array. It's up to you ;)

In your code example, according to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) :

```
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
public class MessageDigestExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String input = "This is a message";
    MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

    //Here "input" is a String
    System.out.println("input : " + input);
    //Here you convert your "input" String into a byte array
    hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input));
    //Here you get the "hash.digest()" result, which is an byte array, then you convert it into some hexadecimal value
    //(just check the library documentation where "Utils.toHex()" function comes from to know what it returns exactly).
    //Finally you cast it into a String value as you print it.
    System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(hash.digest()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this is what I am looking for.

Comment: You are welcome =) don't forget to check the documentation when you are in trouble, it can generally help you to fully understand what you do. And if something is not clear, it is easier for you to ask precise questions on what you don't get !